# Enterprise Wiki new Categories

Tags: managed-metadata, term-store, categories

I have an enterprise wiki, whereby the Categories field links to a Managed Term Set. Users also have the ability to add new Categories on the fly (i'm okay with this) however when they do so, it gets added into the root of the Term Set.

My term set has multiple levels, so my question is, how can users place a new Term they create within a specific category level? For example, if my term set looks like the below, how would a user create a new term and place it as a descendant of Sub Cat 1?

1. Root

   a. Cat 1

   b. Cat 2

   ```
       i. Sub Cat 1

       ii. Sub cat 2
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I quite literally found the answer to this after posting, but turns out there is an "Add New Item" button available on the Categories selector.

So click icon that opens the categories selector and at the top it states "New items are added under the currently selected item." . So whatever Term you have selected, it will be added as a descendant.